# CSV or SQL for a small site

Tags: sql, database, csv

If I wanted to run a small personal site that added, say, 2000 rows of data (150 kb) every hour, would there be any significant difference between using a CSV file or SQL database? I am very new to databases and currently have a prototype that appends data to a CSV file for simplicity, but I would like to know if there are any downsides in speed or memory. I will only need write and lookup. Also, if there is a large amount of redundant data, will a relational database be able to store or detect this efficiently? I do not fully understand the concept.

Edit: this question is not a duplicate of my other question. The other concerns an interchange format that should work between a server and a website, while this question is about a method to store data as a flat file or database.

Comment: `csv` is a file format, `SQL` is a *language* the two are not even comparable.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The two are related: A csv *flat file* and a SQL *relational database*.

Comment: `SQL` stands for `Structured Query Language` there are no requirements to have anything to do with a relational database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSV is a sequential text file, so lookups will be O(n).  That is, it wil take 10x longer to lookup in a file with 10,000 lines than one with 1000.

For this reason, id recommend a SQL database, as they have built in indexing features.  You can use something like Access or SQLlite for next to nothing.

The only real downside to a SQL database is that you have to learn how to use it.

Comment: Can SQL handle redundant data "automatically" or will that take some code?

Comment: The relational model does not permit truly redundant data, however, SQL is a superset of the relational model and has no problem with it.  You just need to add a generated key to the table like an auto number/identifier column.

Answer (score 0):

So, sql has several features that you need to imlement when using CSV.
CSV won't let you create indexes for fast searching.

If you always need all data from a single table (like for application settings), CSV is faster, otherwise not.

What are some disadvantages?

- No indexing
- Cannot be partitioned
- No transactions
- Cannot have NULL values

As per your case as you have large data....its better to go with database rather than using csv.

You can create constraints like unique key constraints to uniquely identify data....There are several features that trival CSV flat file will not support.

Comment: Note: CSV can have null values.